# How do I change the default Bootstrap accordion button?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Wondering if anyone knows how to change the default collapse button for Bootstrap 4, 5 accordion?

I'd like to customize them with fontawesome. Thanks!

Example accordion:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Bootstrap 5 use CSS:

```css
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,...");
}
.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,...");
}
```

(Note can use only one image, as the default CSS rotates it with `rotate(180deg)`)

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/ejrLb0ox/) for an example using FA's `caret-up` & `caret-down`.

---

For Bootstrap 4 -- the Accordion component doesn't use an image.

But if you're including the FA font file you can use (for "+" and "-"):

```css
.accordion .card-header:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f068';
  float: right;
}
.accordion .card-header.collapsed:after {
  content: '\f068';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this.

- I wanted to change arrow icon to + and - icon.
- copied svg icon from icon.bootstrap
- replaced svg tag in below css
- In the copied code, don't forget to replace double quote " to single quote '
- [image: List item]

```
.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-plus-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/><path d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/></svg>");
}
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-dash-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/><path d='M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z'/></svg>");
}
```